# Attaching a swinging object to a rolling object?

Tags: unity, c#

I am new to Unity and attempting to create a platform that hangs down under a roller that runs on rails. I've gathered my objects and come so far but I can't for the life of me work out how to attach the platform to the roller on top without the rope connecting them getting wound up on the roller as it goes along.

Is there a way to make sure only the roller turns but the rope attached just follows it vertically and horizontally?

Comment: I don't work with unity so I don't know how useful this comment will be: consider how this would work in real life: you would need a frame to attach the rope to. The frame would roll over the rails with a few wheels. It sounds to me like the rolling object would need a non-rolling, but moving, parent.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Have you looked at any vehicle examples? for instance, the wheels of a car can roll, but the car chassis doesn't rotate about the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a script that on fixed update matches the position but not rotation. I've never worked with unity's physics constraints but check out the [hinge joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html) and give it full 360 degree of motion